# Stop CollectionView from scrolling during interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I'm trying to stop a UICollectionView from scrolling if the velocity is too low.

Using the delegate method:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
```

I've tried many different approaches, but nothing seems to stop the scrollview. I've tried combinations of:

```
        scrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        scrollView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you're trying to do... If the user drags quickly, but then slows down just before lifting his finger, do you want the scrolling to stop immediately? Or, do you mean if the user is *slowly* dragging, it shouldn't scroll at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the current `contentOffset` as a target offset.

```swift
targetContentOffset.pointee = scrollView.contentOffset
```

Comment: Not sure how I can set the let constant in the delegate methods param? Can you explain more?

Comment: @BuyinBrian `targetContentOffset` is a pointer to an actual target content offset. The pointer itself is immutable, but the value it points to *is*. You can access this value through `pointee` property and then mutate it.

Comment: There are multiple pointer types in Swift, `UnsafeMutablePointer`, as its name suggests, allows you to mutate the value it is pointing to.